# powerbi scatterplot doesn't plot correctly a bunch of datapoints

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've created two field parameters Price and Km.
When I plot the data there are a few of them which doesn't get a x value (km) even if in the fact table the data is present (as seen in the multirow card). Can't understand why cause most of the data are plotted correctly so really no clue how to further investigate it.

[image: scatterplot and]